# Check if iterator's type is reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

Is there a way to check if iterator passed as arg to fnc is reverse_iterator? Are there any iterator traits function I could use?

Comment: There are indeeds [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) that might be possible to use.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? I have a hard time coming up with a good use case.

Answer (score 10):

It's trivial to write with a partial specialization:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Iter>
  struct is_reverse_iterator
  : std::false_type { };

template<typename Iter>
  struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>
  : std::true_type { };
```

Although as pointed out below, this doesn't handle the (IMHO unlikely) case of a "reverse-reverse" iterator. The slightly less trivial version in Bathsheba's answer handles that case correctly.

Comment: This will not handle `std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>` well. The other answer will.

Comment: Possibly the two answers do usefully different things with that tricky case. Depending why you want to know whether or not it's a `reverse_iterator`, you might want to treat a double-reverse iterator as being one (because it is indeed of a type which is an instantiation of `reverse_iterator`) or as not being one (because it iterates "forwards", whatever that means in context).

Answer (score 7):

Some code I use in production:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename I>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename I>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<I>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, !is_reverse_iterator<I>::value>
{
};
```

Comment: +1 . Thanks. A couple of new stuff from std library for a newbie like me. Never knew of `std::integral_constant`, `std::false_type`

Comment: "Some code I use in production" - what's your use case? Like Marc Glisse, I'm not seeing why you'd want to do this.