# Should reversing a reverse_iterator give a forward iterator of the original type?

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

I naively expected this program to compile and run with a success status:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "foo";
    auto forward_iter = s.begin();
    auto reverse_iter = std::make_reverse_iterator(forward_iter);
    auto third_iter = std::make_reverse_iterator(reverse_iter);
    return forward_iter != third_iter;
}
```

It fails to compile, because the type of `third_iter` isn't the same as that of the `forward_iter` we started with; instead it's a `reverse_iterator<reverse_iterator<normal_iterator>>`:

```
0.cpp:10:25: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’)
     return forward_iter != third_iter;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Re-reading the documentation, it appears that `std::make_reverse_iterator(it)` is specified to always wrap `it`, *even if `it` is already a reverse iterator* (and to some extent that makes sense, because we'll be expecting to use `reverse_iterator` members (i.e. `base()`).

Is there a standard way to swap between normal (forward) and wrapped (reverse) iterators, without knowing which type I have?  Or do I need to write a SFINAE pair of functions to return `std::make_reverse_iterator(it)` and `it.base()` appropriately?

Comment: Please provide the code in which you actually need this possibility.

Comment: You're going to have to write your own `reverse_iterator` function that will swap it around.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360697/determine-if-a-c-iterator-is-reverse) should help with that.

Comment: @r3musn0x - I'll stick with the [mcve], if that's okay.  No need to bulk the question with too much code.  In summary, it's a palindrome test - a function that's passed a forward and a reverse iterator and uses `std::mismatch()` to see how big a palindrome centred on the point could be.  I could be able to constrain the arguments a bit more so that the forward iterator has to come first (or last)...

Comment: @Nathan That's what I'm resigned to hearing.  I might do that and write a self-answer (and if somebody creates a better technique, that's clear for them to add to).

Comment: @TobySpeight, it's just not clear why can't you use `base()` when you need to. Are you using `std::make_reverse_iterator` in the context when you don't know whether it's already reversed? I just can't really imagine this use case.

Comment: @r3musn0x Yes, my function needs a forward and a reverse iterator, and needs to be able to reverse one of them to get a pair of iterators for its next step.  That's when I ran into this, because I was surprised not to get back what I started with.  I might be able to constrain it to know which is the original and which is the reverse in this particular case, but it seems a useful thing to know the general answer to, as well.

Comment: @r3musn0x, I thought I was going to need it when writing my [review of _Conway's Game of Life command line program in C++_](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204002), but in the end, I managed to reorganise the code to make it unnecessary.  I'm still glad I asked, as I at least learnt something in the process.

Answer (score 2):

> Should reversing a reverse_iterator give a forward iterator of the original type?

No. Or at least, that's not how `make_reverse_iterator` has been specified. The return type is specified to be `reverse_iterator<Iterator>` in the standard.

> Is there a standard way to swap between normal (forward) and wrapped (reverse) iterators, without knowing which type I have?

No. Not as far as I know.

> Or do I need to write a SFINAE pair of functions to return `std::make_reverse_iterator(it)` and `it.base()` appropriately?

You can write it. I can't say whether you need it.

Here's one implementation:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408829/2079303
template<typename I>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type {};

template<typename I>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<I>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, !is_reverse_iterator<I>::value> {};

template<class It>
auto
reverse_or_base(It&& i)
{
    if constexpr (is_reverse_iterator<std::decay_t<It>>())
        return i.base();
    else
        return std::make_reverse_iterator(std::forward<It>(i));
}
```

And a test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<
            decltype(reverse_or_base(v.rbegin())),
            std::vector<int>::iterator
        >
    );
    assert(v.end() == reverse_or_base(v.rbegin()));

    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<
            decltype(reverse_or_base(v.begin())),
            std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator
        >
    );
    assert(v.rend() == reverse_or_base(v.begin()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make a pair of small functions to swap between forward and reverse iterators:

```
template<typename Iter>
auto toggle_iterator_direction(Iter it) {
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(it);
}

template<typename Iter>
auto toggle_iterator_direction(std::reverse_iterator<Iter> it) {
    return it.base();
}
```

And an alternative version, using a helper type template, modelled on [an answer to *Determine if a (c++) iterator is reverse*](/a/22361499):

```
template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type {};

template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<Iter>> : std::true_type {};


template<typename Iter>
auto toggle_iterator_direction(Iter it) {
    if constexpr (is_reverse_iterator<Iter>())
        return it.base();
    else
        return std::make_reverse_iterator(it);
}
```

Both of these fix the modified test program:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "foo";
    auto forward_iter = s.begin();
    auto reverse_iter = toggle_iterator_direction(forward_iter);
    auto third_iter = toggle_iterator_direction(reverse_iter);
    return forward_iter != third_iter;
}
```

Comment: I think the overloaded version is best because it's simpler.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I wrote second.