Why can't I compare a double-reversed iterator with a plain iterator?
Consider the following code:
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container, typename Pred>
bool foo(const Container c, Pred p) {
    auto first = std::find_if(std::cend(c), std::cend(c), p);
    auto last = std::find_if(
        std::make_reverse_iterator(std::cend(c)),
        std::make_reverse_iterator(std::cbegin(c)),
        p);
    return std::make_reverse_iterator(last) - first > 5;
}

Why does this refuse to compile? Shouldn't the reverse-of-a-reverse-iterator be compatible with a regular iterator?
Notes:

If I turn first into a reverse_iterator, instead of the other way around, the code will compile. But it's not what I want to do, for reasons.
This question asks why a double-reverse iterator should not just have the original iterator's type, which is a bigger ask.
The problem should be the same for other containers, e.g. std::vector.


Typo?  Shouldn't the return statement be return last - std::reverse_iterator(first) > 5; to turn first into a reverse iterator like last already is?

@NathanOliver: That will work, but it's not my question. Let me clarify.

why not calling std::reverse_iterator::base?

@einpoklum I get what you are really trying to ask, and the reason it fails is that std::reverse_iterator is not the same type as Container::itrerator.  Thats why you get the error.

@NathanOliver: I realize that they're not formally the same. But - why should they not be effectively the same? Or at the very least, comparable?

Note that std::reverse_iterator(last) calls the copy constructor rather than reversing it again. You can use std::make_reverse_iterator(last) if you want to reverse it twice, but it still won't work because it isn't the same as the original iterator type.

@einpoklum Because std::reverse_iterator only has operators defined for other std::reverse_iterators

I wonder why std::make_reverse_iterator leads to same issue: https://godbolt.org/z/ncKjzM74q IMO this function should be able to see it already received reversed_iterator and fallback to base iterator. This would be a nice feature.

Iterators should not be universally compatible. For example it is senseless to compare an iterator on a std::vector<T> with an iterator on a std::list<T>. No special relation was defined between your iterator C::const_iterator and std::reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<C::const_iterator>>, so they are not compatible. In theory, it may be possible to require that std::make_reverse_iterator detect when it wraps a std::reverse_iterator and return the base iterator, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I suspect adding that feature now would cause backwards compatibility issues

@MarekR std::make_reverse_iterator creates a reverse_iterator object.  Its never going to not make a reverse_iterator object. What it does is change the direction the iterator iterates.

@interjay: Noted, corrected. Still, why should a double-reversed iterator not be comparable with a never-reversed one?

@FrançoisAndrieux: Nobody asked for universal compatibility, just for compatibility under double-reversal.

@NathanOliver my point was that in case of using reverse_iterator it is impossible to create specialization which will give back original iterator. In case of make_reverse_iterator such specialization should not be a problem.

@NathanOliver I think the idea is that make_reverse_iterator could still reverse the direction if, in the case of reversing a reverse_iterator, it returns its base member instead of wrapping it in an additional reverse_iterator. It isn't allowed to, but had the function's requirements been defined differently it (or a similar function) could work that way.

@MarekR  I think you would need partial specialization to make that work and that's not allowed for function templates.

@Marek: "why not calling std::reverse_iterator::base" <- 1. Are you asking me? 2. That's a type, what do you suggest I actually call?

@einpoklum My comment is meant to highlight that the compatibility for double-reversal is not supported simply because it falls under the "unrelated iterator types" umbrella.

Because nobody asked for this feature?

auto first = std::find_if(std::cend(c), std::cend(c), p);? Why not just make it auto first = std::cend(c);?

Note that std::views::reverse does work how you expect it too and std::views::reverse(std::views::reverse(views)) is not a reverse_view (if views wasn't originally a reverse_view)

@n.m.couldbeanAI Many people have: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52429377

@n.m.couldbeanAI: That can't be it...

@einpoklum Maybe nobody made a formal proposition before it became impossible to integrate without breaking backwards compatibility (before C++14 was finalized).

its like C++11 shipping with make_shared but not make_unique.

@FrançoisAndrieux: How would adding comparability break backwards compatibility? :-(

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52429377 that answers clearly that the standard requires the function to return a reverse iterator whereas the OP expects a forward iterator.

Cam you show a compelling reason why this feature is needed (as opposed to nice)? You always can reverse the second iterator.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: 1. You want to localize the existence of reverse iterators if you're passing those iterators around, because if you don't, it is quite easy to confuse the reversed and unreversed, advance the wrong way etc.  2.  Maybe you want to do more work with the reversed iterator, not just this single comparison; your suggesting would mean other things now have to be force-reversed to match its type.

In this post I am dodging the main question, while proposing a cheap workaround:
template<typename iter> //default 
struct consistent_reverse_type_nest
: std::type_identity<std::reverse_iterator<iter>> {};

template<typename iter> //special 
struct consistent_reverse_type_nest
<std::reverse_iterator<iter>>
: std::type_identity<iter>> {};

template<typename Iter>
using consistent_reverse_type = 
typename consistent_reverse_type_nest::type;

Now we can define the function:
tenplate <typename Iter>
constexper auto make_consistent_reverse_iterator(Iter it)
-> consistent_reverse_type<Iter>
{
   if constexpr(
      requires(Iter tst)
          { {tst.base()}->std::same_as<consistent_reverse_type<Iter>> }
   )
      return it.base();
   else std::make_reverse_iterator(it);
};

Fixing <ranges> is both simpler and harder. We just need a view CPO, but there's no std boilerplate CRTP to define the CPO and let std define the pipe operator (operator |).
The OP's question triggers a more fundamental question of optimizing chained adapters, via type algebra to get a simpler final view/iterator type.
